# Firebase is only responding with a single document when I query it even though multiple meet the query criteria

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to write a cloud function that returns users near a specific location.  get_nearby() returns a list of tuples containing upper and lower bounds for a geohash query, and then this loop should query firebase for users within those geohashes.

```
user_ref = db.collection(u'users')

db_response = []
for query_range in get_nearby(lat, long, radius):
    query = user_ref.where(u'geohash', u'>=', query_range[0]).where(u'geohash', u'<=', query_range[1]).get()
    for el in query:
        db_response.append(el.to_dict())
```

For some reason when I run this code, it returns only one document from my database, even though there are three other documents with the same geohash as that one.  I know the documents are there, and they do get returned when I request the entire collection.  What am I missing here?

edit:
The database currently has 4 records in it, 3 of which should be returned in this query:

```
{
    {name: "Trevor",  geohash: "dnvtz"}, #this is the one that gets returned
    {name: "Test",  geohash: "dnvtz"},
    {name: "Test",  geohash: "dnvtz"}
}
```

query_range is a tuple with two values.  A lower and upper bound geohash.  In this case, it's ("dnvt0", "dnvtz").

Comment: Since we don't know the value of `query_range`, nor the contents of the database, it's not really possible for us to say what's going wrong here.

Comment: I'll suggest that you edit the question to put all relevant information in the question, rather than hoping someone will spot it in the comments.

Comment: @DougStevenson edited, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to clear all documents from my database and then generate a new set of sample data to work with (everything there was only for testing anyway, nothing important).  After pushing the new data to Firestore, everything is working.  My only assumption is that even though the strings matched up, I'd used the wrong encoding on some of them.